# Show that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\Sigma_{i=0}^k \binom{n}{3i}}{2^n} = \frac{1}{3}$

Tags: combinatorics, limits, binomial-theorem

Let $n =  3k$  . Show that $\displaystyle{\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\Sigma_{i=0}^k \binom{n}{3i}}{2^n} = \frac{1}{3}}$ . In other words, the sum of every third element of the nth row of the Pascal triangle is roughly one third of the sum of all elements of that row; after this,  generalize the result.

attempt:

$\displaystyle{\begin{array}{ll}
\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \displaystyle{\frac{\Sigma_{i=0}^k \binom{3k}{3i}}{2^n}} & = \\\\ 
\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \displaystyle{\frac{\binom{3k}{0} + \binom{3k}{3} + \binom{3k}{6} + \cdot \cdot \cdot + \binom{3k}{k} }{2^n}} & = \\\\
\lim_\limits{n \rightarrow \infty} \displaystyle{\frac{\frac{3k!}{0! 3k!} + \frac{3k!}{3!(3k-3)!} + \frac{3k!}{6!(3k-6)!} + \cdot \cdot \cdot + \frac{3k!}{3k!(3k - 3k)!} }{2^n}} & = \\\\
\lim_\limits{n \rightarrow \infty} \displaystyle{\frac{\frac{1}{1} + \frac{3k (3k-1)(3k-2)(3k-3)....2 \cdot 1}{3!(3k-3)!} + \frac{3k(3k-1)(3k-2)...(3k-6)...2.1}{6!(3k-6)!} + \cdot \cdot \cdot + \frac{1}{1} }{2^n}} & = \\\\
\lim_\limits{n \rightarrow \infty} \displaystyle{\frac{\frac{1}{1} + \frac{3k (3k-1)(3k-2)(3k-3)}{3!} + \frac{3k(3k-1)(3k-2)...(3k-5)}{6!} + \cdot \cdot \cdot + \frac{1}{1} }{2^n}}
\end{array}}$

I am stuck. If $n = 3k$ approaches infinity then it seems that we would have $0$ on the numerator and so the expression would go to $0$ and not $1/3$ .
Could someone please help me ? and give me some feedback. Thank you

Comment: You should probably have $2^n$ (the sum of all the entries in the $n$-th row) and not $2$ in the denominator.

Comment: Editing: I used displaystyle and array, your version was very small for reading.

Comment: Your question in combinatoric language is in the following form. If we have a set of size $n$, why the ratio of all subsets of size $0$ to $3k$ to all subsets of the set, tend to $\frac{1}{3}$ when $n$ is an enough large number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $\omega=\exp\left(\frac{2\pi i}{3}\right)$. The characteristic function of the integers $n$ of the form $3k$ can be written as $\frac{1+\omega^n+\omega^{2n}}{3}$ (this is the principle behind the [discrete Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform)) hence

$$ \sum_{i\geq 0}\binom{n}{3i} = \frac{1}{3}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}(1+\omega^k+\omega^{2k})=\frac{2^n+(1+\omega)^n+(1+\omega^2)^n}{3}$$
and accidentally both $1+\omega$ and $1+\omega^2$ have unit modulus, hence the term $(1+\omega)^n+(1+\omega^2)^n$ is bounded by $2$ in modulus, regardless of $n$. It follows that
$$ \lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{i\geq 0}\binom{n}{3i}=\color{red}{\frac{1}{3}} $$
as wanted. In other terms,

> If we consider a random subset of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$, its cardinality equals $3k$ for some $k\in\mathbb{N}$
>  with a probability closer and closer to $\frac{1}{3}$ as $n$ increases.

That holds also if $3$ is replaced by $4,5,6,7,\ldots$, but the speed of convergence is quite different:
 to prove it (through the DFT) is an interesting exercise I leave to the reader / to the OP.

Comment: thanks for your answer. But I could not find this principle in my book, I have not learned this. Do you think I can still apply this for a combinatorics class?

Comment: @Mahidevran: the DFT is a key technique in (analytic) combinatorics, and I am not aware of simpler methods for proving the same, hence definitely yes.

Comment: First time I see this characterization of $\chi_{kn}$ with roots of unity, although it seems so obvious now that I see it. I mean I have already used similar tricks like in calculating $\sum\frac 1{5n!}$ for instance, but it never tilted as a general principle for selecting some given multiples of $n$.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> As $\ds{k \to \infty}$:

\begin{align}
{1 \over 8^{k}}\sum_{i = 0}^{k}{3k \choose 3i} & \sim
{1 \over 8^{k}}\sum_{i = 0}^{k}
{3k \choose 3k/2}\exp\pars{-\,{6\bracks{i - k/2}^{2} \over k}}
\\[5mm] & \sim
\root{\pi \over 6}{k^{1/2} \over 8^{k}}{3k \choose 3k/2} \to
\bbx{\ds{{1 \over 3}\quad\mbox{as}\ k \to \infty}}
\end{align}

> That is an application of *'Laplace Method for Sums'* as explained in, for example, page $761$ of $\ds{\bbox[8px,#efe,border:1px dotted navy]{Analytic\ Combinatorics}}$ by Philipe Flajolet and Robert Sedgewick, Cambridge University Press 2009.